# Validate only if data filled

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-validate

Well, I need to implement this criteria in one of the form field in my application, the rules goes like:-

input_field,Criteria=>It needs to be validated only if the "input_field" has values in it, if its empty no need to validate, well the thing is I have fixed up the "second-validation" method for that field, i.e to check digits and symbols and bla bla bla.....

But the problem is I need to apply the second validation only if the field is filled. I couldn't come up with any solution, since being new to javascript and all.

And I am using JQuery validator, for the form.

Comment: please share your code ans how the second validator is used

Comment: Try adding the HTML5 [`required` attribute](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#the-required-attribute) for starters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your custom validation function like

```
$.validator.addMethod(
    "YourCustomValidation",

function (value, element) {
    if ($('#yourField').val().length == 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        //do validation here and return true false
    }
});
```

Then use this validation function as

```
yourField: {
    YourCustomValidation:true
}
```

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 1):

```
second_field: {
    required: {
        depends: function () {
            if ($('#second_field').val().length > 0) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just `return ($('#second_field').val().length > 0);`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var isNull = function (val) {
    if ((typeof val == 'undefined') || (val == null))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

var your_field_val = 'data';

if (isNull(your_field_val)) {
    // null or empty
} else {
    // not null..validate your field
}
```